# Mocking Sequelize functions to expect output

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I am new to the concept of unit testing and I have to test write the test for my "create" function that stores a record to the database table(mySQL). Here's my code for the controller :

```
'use strict'
var todo = require('../../../repository/todo-repo')
module.exports = {
 collect: (req,res,next)=>{
      var fields = ['id','title','description'];
      var reqdata = new req.collect(req,fields);

      req.task_data = reqdata.collect(req,res)
      if(!req.task_data.length) return (new Error("no values provided"))
      console.log(req.task_data);
      next();
  },
 create: (req,res,next) =>{
      var options = {
      data:req.task_data
     }
    todo.create(options,success,error)
    function success(result){
     console.log(result);
     }
    function error(err){
      if(err) return (err)
     }
   }
}
```

And here's my test code :

```
var chai = require('chai')
var expect = chai.expect;
var todo = require('../controllers/api/todo/todo')
var todomodal = require('../models/todo')
var create = todo.create;
var sinon = require('sinon');

  describe('create',()=>{
   it('should add data to the todo table',(done)=>{
    var req = {
     task_data:{
     title:"here",
     description:"details to follow"
      }
   }
  var id = create(req,null,null)
  console.log("=>>",id);
  expect(id).to.be.a('string')
  done()
  })
})
```

How do I write the test to expect a certain result from my function. Let's say I would like to send the test data to the function and expect the created record's id to be an integer. Since sequelize returns success and error two callbacks, how do I handle that?